# Docker bidirectional communication between containers

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose

I'm looking out to setup bidirectional communication between docker containers.I have following containers:

```
1.Apache
2.Tomcat A
3.Tomcat B
4.Tomcat C
5.MySQL
```

Apache acts as a reverse proxy and forwards requests to Tomcat A,B and C.All Tomcat containers will communicate with MySQL database.As of now I have links in Apache to send requests to tomcat containers and tomcat containers have links to communicate with MySQL database.
Now I need to establish bidirectional communication between tomcat containers Like Tomcat A wants to talk with Tomcat B and Tomcat C and vice versa.How we can achieve this with Docker Compose ? Is it possible to provide bidirectional links in docker-compose.yml file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Links are not bidirectional so you can't achieve it with that.

What you can do is to set your containers in the same network, so they can access each other via their container name.

For example

```
docker network create newnetwork
docker run -d --name apache --net=newnetwork Apache
docker run -d --name tomcatA --net=newnetwork TomcatA
...
```

Doing that, the container apache will be able to ping/access tomcatA, and tomcatA will be able to ping/access apache.

Have a look at how to integrate networks with docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specifying-custom-networks

I'm not sure of this part, but since docker ~1.10, it seems that you do not need to create a network, the default network connects all the containers together so you can already ping/access each containers from the others via their name. (look at the /etc/hosts file in the containers, if you see the other containers name and their IP you're good to go)

Comment: Thanks much. Yes I'm using docker ~1.11 now and it seems that by default docker compose automatically creates a single network based on project name with "bridge" driver and each container for a service joins that network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.
I tried to ping container 2 (with its container name) from container 1 and it is working as expected.  But don't have host entries pointing other container name and IP address in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Ok maybe /etc/hosts was an old implementation and they are using a new mechanism now, I'll look into it